# Postgresql database altering table with mln rows

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I have table with mln rows and I want to add new column with default value 0. Is it true  way to do this? is it take too long time or not please give me best way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Since Postgres 11 adding a column with a constant default value, will not rewrite the entire table, so the actual ALTER TABLE command will only take a few milliseconds - once it was able to obtain a lock.

So the best way to do it, is

```
alter table the_table
   add new_column integer default 0;
```